# APK file is not getting attach in gmail

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I am trying to upload my apk file on the gmail but it is showing "Infected virus" and not attaching.

OS: Ubuntu
IDE: Eclipse

I have also search on Internet for this and found that it may happen because of any lib file used in project. But which lib/jar should i remove, all are useful in this project.

```
android-support-v4.jar
httpclient-4.4-alpha1.jar
httpcore-4.4-alpha1.jar
httpmime-4.4-alpha1.jar
jackson-annotations-2.0.2.jar
jackson-core-2.0.2.jar
jackson-databind-2.0.2.jar
library-1.0.15.jar
picasso-2.2.0.jar
```

Please someone help, if any idea.

Comment: you cant upload .exe apk etc executable files in gmail directly you should zip it and upload

Comment: I did it but still it is not uploading.

Comment: It can check the zip. I've in the past zipped it then renamed the zip to a different extention, but I'd bet google has gotten around that.

Try using another file hosting service maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Change extension from .apk to .doc and than upload . It will work.

Comment: Will it install in device from mail?? If i'll do it.

Comment: No you have to change its extension when you download it in device or pc

Comment: I have changed .apk to .doc but it is not even attaching.... gmail is throwing the same message..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81934/discussion-between-anand-savjani-and-vid).